# Where does Bastion store its configuration/settings?

Tags: pc, bastion

I just picked up Bastion on Steam and ran into a small problem.

By default, the game was running at my monitor's native resolution of 2560x1440, but I went to the in-game options menu and selected a different resolution by mistake. The problem is, the list of available resolutions *doesn't have a scrollbar*, so now I can't change it back! The highest resolution I see in the list is 1920x1200.

Since I just purchased the game I don't have any saved games to worry about, so I just want to wipe any settings/config files and start from the defaults. Where does Bastion keep its settings, or more importantly, **how can I reset the resolution**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a quote from the developers:

> **Q:** I changed the in-game resolution, how can I restore the original settings?
>
> > **A:** The game will auto-detect your monitor's proper resolution on start-up. If you change your resolution and the proper one is not available in the options menu, you can have it auto-detect again by deleting your profile here (exact location may vary): **"\Program Files\Steam\userdata\33142021\107100\local"**

[Source](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2061171)

Answer (score 6):

On linux (Humble Indie Bundle 5 version) the information is stored in `~/.SupergiantGames/Bastion/`
For Windows 7 and the bundle it's in `%USERPROFILE%\Saved Games\Bastion\`